# Teacher insists to use if statement instead of while statement, while with while statement my code works

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having a little problem here.
We been told to program some simple things but I can't run the code perfectly with if statement.
With while statements, my code works perfectly but teacher insists not to use it.
While statement is a loop right?
He said "Do not use loops!".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Flight
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        // Naming a scanner //
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prints text //
        System.out.println("Enter flight day: ");
        // Data insert //
        int flyDay = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter flight hour: ");
        int flyHour = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter flight minute: ");
        int flyMinute = scan.nextInt();

        //// Length ///
        System.out.println("Enter flight's length in hours:");
        int departureHour = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter flight's length in minutes:");
        int departureMin = scan.nextInt();

        // While minute is beyond 60 (including) //
        departureMin += flyMinute;
        while(departureMin >= 60) {
            departureHour++;
            departureMin-=60;
        }

        // While hour is beyond 24 (including) //
        departureHour += flyHour;
        while(departureHour >= 24)
        {
            flyDay++;
            departureHour-=24;
        }

        // While day is beyond 8 (including) //
        while(flyDay >=8)
        flyDay-=7;

        // Prints arrival time according to the data inserted above //
        System.out.println("the supposed arrival time is: day- " + flyDay + ", hour- " + departureHour + ", minute- " + departureMin);
    }
}
```

If I switch the while statements into if statements the code will not work properly.
Any help?

Comment: Your teacher is right. Maybe you need to do the maths with pencil and paper and refactor your code.

Comment: Hint: The `/` and `%` operators may come in handy.

Comment: Only because the code works, it doesn't mean it is a good code. Your `while` can be reduced to an `if` statement using `%` and `/`, which means you can do just one check instead of a lot of loops, so your teacher is just right.

Comment: I'm not a math expert :( I don't know what to do, I just switched to if and the code just doesn't work properly, I don't know any other way, can you guys please help me fix the code and teach me what's wrong in it? ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is correct, it's not appropriate to use a loop here, even though it works.

Your teacher probably wants you to use the [remainder (`%`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) (frequently called "modulus") operator and the [division (`/`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) operator.

Comment: But I don't know any other way to run this code properly other than using loops. Can you help me fix it? :/

Comment: @Luminous: I think if you read up on the operators above, you'll see how they apply to updating the hours and minutes. I'll give you this hint: `75 / 60` is `1` (because this is integer math), and `75 % 60` is `15`. 75 minutes is, of course, 1 hour and 15 minutes...

Comment: tbh, I don't know math, dunno integers, dunno %'s either. I did read what they wrote, that seems chinese to me. Where can I learn math in a level that fits java's easy level? btw, a friend gave me a code that  works, it has no if or while statements, but it does have those complicated stuff you guys stated above this comment :( math is hard, wish I could understand it clearer.

Comment: @Luminous: Integers, division, and remainders are basic math. I suggest sitting down with your teacher and talking with him/her about this, explaining you don't know what an integer is, don't understand remainders, etc., and asking for help/guidance.

Comment: @Luminous: FWIW: In math, an "integer" is a whole number, such as 1 or 2 or 537. They don't have a fractional portion (so 1.5 is not an integer, because it has *part* of a number in it). Integer division is how many times you can take one number from another before you don't have enough left to keep going. In integer division, 7 / 2 = 3 because you can only take 2 from 7 three times before you only have 1 left (remaining), so you can't do it again. That 1 you have left is called the *remainder*. That's what `%` gives you. So 7 / 2 = 3 (the result) and 7 % 2 = 1 (the remainder).

Comment: Oh oh I get it now! So it's like 15 / 7 = 2 right? DAM IM SO EXCITED NOW LMFAO, see? math can be easy if it's explained RIGHT and CLEAR. Most education institutions bring tough teachers cuz they think students can learn better from them, if they only made math fun and interesting by clear explanation or a little patient, everyone could succeed in math. I'm sick of this world and people's idiocy. I read your post only ONCE and understood everything without re-reading it. It was all clear and damn straight to the point. I appreciate it and I wish all math teachers could teach like you do.